Having a Base Class Pointer to access methods of all classes in the inheritance hierarchy
I have this hierarchy. 'Bird' as a base class, 'FlyingBird' is a child of 'Bird', and 'Parrot' is a child of 'FlyingBird'. I create a Bird* that points to a Parrot object in main().
What I don't understand is I cannot access member functions of any classes. Only methods in the 'Bird' class can be accessed.
Even though, 'FlyingBird' and 'Parrot' classes are part of the 'Bird' inheritance hierarchy.
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Bird
{
private:
    std::string type;
public:
    Bird(std::string type)
        : type(type) {

    }

    virtual void eat()
    {
        std::cout << type << " is eating\n";
    }

    virtual void walk()
    {
        std::cout << type << " is walking\n";
    }

    virtual std::string getType() const final {
        return type;
    }

    virtual ~Bird() {}
};

class FlyingBird : public Bird
{
private:
    std::string wingSize;

public:
    FlyingBird(std::string type, std::string wingSize)
        : Bird(type), wingSize(wingSize) {

    }

    virtual void fly()
    {
        std::cout << this->getType() << " is flying\n";
    }

    virtual ~FlyingBird() {}
};

class Parrot : public FlyingBird
{
public:
    Parrot(std::string type, std::string wingSize)
        : FlyingBird(type, wingSize) {

    }

    virtual ~Parrot() {}
};

int main()
{

    // This is unable to call fly()
    Bird* parrot = new Parrot("Blue Parrot", "Large");
    parrot->fly();

    // But this can
    Parrot parrot1("Yellow Parrot", "Extra large");
    parrot1.fly();
}


The base class must have the method that you want to override in the derive class, otherwise there is nothing to be overriden. Note c++ is a statically typed language. FlyingBird contains a fly method while Bird doesn't.

Why do you write all of your functions as virtual ?

Basically FlyingBird::fly() does not actually override any fly method from base since there is no such method Bird::fly() in base. I would recommend using a good c++ book

When you have a Bird*, you can only use the Bird interface - all you know is that it is a Bird. This is usually explained in the introduction to polymorphism in any good book.

@user12002570
I will add some polymorphic functionalities later, that is why some are virtual (there is the getType() that does not need virtual, I will fix it, thanks)

There are static type and dynamic type. And the static type must contain the method fly but in case of Bird* parrot, there is no such method in Bird.

Also always post complete error along with your question. parrot.fly() won't compile for the reasons mentioned in my other comments.

This question asks "why". For the related "how" question, see Access derived class member from base class pointer (Note: not recommended in most cases)

Alright, let's clarify a few things. First of all, how inheritance works on a high-level. I'll keep the explanations simple and won't go too much into how C++ or the compilers do their magic to achieve this. Most of what I say will apply to other OOP languages as well (think Java, C# and in general any language supporting inheritance).
First of all, while it's true that inheritance is a bidirectional relationship, and from some points of view, you can look at it that way, it all comes down to how you use it. In OOP there is a thing called casting between types, which for short means converting one type into a compatible type. A compatible type is decided by inheritance and has nothing to do with members (meaning the variable fields or functions).
So even though 2 classes, A theoretical Application class and Person, have a Run() function, you can't convert between them if there is no relationship between them.
Casting can be done in various way, the recommended one for C++ is done using dynamic_cast. There are some cases where static_cast can be used and there's also the non-recommended C-style cast.
Enough of the intro, let's get back to your use-case. So how does the relationship of a parent-child work? Well, much like in real-life. Parents from one generation know things, they learned a lot in school, high school and uni, they read books and have a certain life experience. However, in the approximately 60 years from their birth to the point their child becomes an adult, things change. New information appears, new technology, new concepts, things previously thought known now appear incorrect due to newer evidence.
Let's think pragmatically: imagine if you could go back in time 75 years ago and tell your parent or grandparent that not only computers would be common to everyone, but they'll be a thing that's no more than 8x8 cm and you can wear on your wrist and it can have immense calculation power. Or that you can know the real-time position of a courier delivering your food. Or be immersed in VR and "see" a digital representation of someone from across the globe? Things change and evolve. The problem is, in most cases, our parents or grandparents can't adopt to these new concepts.
Coming back to our situation, that means that children will benefit from the knowledge they gain from parents, but chances are, the parent can't use what the child knows. Why? Different generation.
So a FlyingBird, the child class, can know and use what the Bird class does, but the Bird can't access what FlyingBird has. Think about it another way, how can a parent class know in advance what a child class can do?
As for the relationship in code, you can do this:
Bird* parrot = new Parrot("Blue Parrot", "Large");

And you can do this:
void StudyBird(Bird* bird);

Bird* bird = new Bird("AnyBird");
Bird* parrot1 = new Parrot("Blue Parrot", "Large");
Parrot* parrot2 = new Parrot("Blue Parrot", "Large");

StudyBird(bird);
StudyBird(parrot1);
StudyBird(parrot2);

But there are limitations when it's the other way around:
void StudyParrot(Parrot* bird);

Bird* bird = new Bird("AnyBird");
Bird* parrot1 = new Parrot("Blue Parrot", "Large");
Parrot* parrot2 = new Parrot("Blue Parrot", "Large");

//StudyParrot(bird);  <-- this won't work
StudyParrot(dynamic_cast<Parrot*>(parrot1));
StudyParrot(parrot2);

Of course, inheritance is one big chapter that has a lot more underneath. Polymorphism is one aspect as are virtual functions. Depending on how deep you want to get into the topic, the explanation can become quite long.

The problem is that the static type of the expression *parrot is Bird and for parrot->fly() to work it must contain a fly method. But since Bird does not have any such method, we get the error error: 'class Bird' has no member named 'fly'.
Also, note that FlyingBird::fly() does not actually override any method named fly from Base because there is no such virtual method in Base.

The thing is not all birds can fly(), therefore, adding a fly() method to the 'Bird' class make all other birds can fly(). That is why the tree points to 2 different directions, 'FlyingBird' and, will add later, 'SwimmingBird'.
Parrot inherit from FlyingBird,
and later on, Duck inherit from 'SwimmingBird'

@HarryVu Then you can make that method pure virtual in the base class like virtual void fly() = 0;.

I could. But any class that extends 'Bird' has to override the pure function fly(), which, in the end, still makes all birds can fly().
What I want to achieve here is to design a hierarchy that look similar to that in JAVA.
That is why I didn't add fly() to 'Bird' in the first place. I only want a specific type of bird that can only do what it can. Like a DUCK that can swim(), or a PARROT that can fly()

"What I want to achieve here is to design a hierarchy that look similar to that in JAVA." . Then use Java. This is C++. StackOverflow is full of questions of "Why can't I do X thing in language A which is easily done in language B?". Each language has its own paradigms. You can't "force" a language to be like another.

Don't get heated here, I am learning a new language, and I am figuring out whether C++ can have similar design to JAVA. But based on your answer, it is a clear NO. It just that I spent quite a while getting it to behave like JAVA, now I've got my answer. Thanks a lot mate.

@HarryVu The thing is not all birds can fly() -- But all birds have wings.  Maybe you should reconsider your design so that a Bird has a WingsTraits class, where one of the traits is whether the wings can be used to fly.

@HarryVu Don't misinterpret it, as text doesn't show emotions. It wasn't meant as an attack, but rather, don't have expectations of (almost) copy paste. As I said in my answer, a lot of concepts do carry on between languages. If you want an example where I do wish some java-ism would be in C++, that's the strong enums from Java where you can also declare helper functions inside them. While not really needed in C++, they wouldn't hurt either. AFAIK the first Java version (irrelevant now) was strongly based on C++ so the core concepts will seem familiar. C++ is beautiful. Good luck studying it.

@PaulMcKenzieI am sure that it can be redesigned to work in a similar way with some touch here and there. I will think of it in a different way, as you have suggested

@TheNomad
Words do show emotion. Anyways, in this context, I was sure you weren't meant in a negative way, but rather in an educative approach, trying to tell me that every language is unique, and that I should adapt. Once again, thank you so much for the explanation. There is still so much for me to learn.

@HarryVu You would encounter exactly the same issue in Java, so it is very unclear what you're trying to replicate.

@molbdnilo
Looks like I have mistaken everything this entire time. Prior to posting this question I have never instantiate an object using "base class" type ( Bird duck = new Duck() ) but I always do this ( Duck duck = new Duck() ). The only time where I instantiate using the former method is with List ( List list0 = new ArrayList<>();  List list1 = new LinkedList<>() ).

@molbdnilo
Since I always used methods that that are common to both types of Lists (declare in the List interface, like add(), remove(), etc), I assume that "list0", and "list1" objects can access all methods in the hierarchy (even methods that are specific to ArrayList or LinkedList). With you bringing this up, I have figured out my stupidity.

@HarryVu "List list0 = new ArrayList<>(); List list1 = new LinkedList<>()"*. OK, but why? Just use the proper types. The only time you'd need to do this is when you want to take advantage of polymorphism, not to write less letters because "List" is shorter as a name or because "it has almost the same methods". That's not the point of inheritance or polymorphism.

@HarryVu To understand the impact, let's say you write an open source API. Ignore the language, it can be anything, an imaginary language. In it we have a base class List and a child LinkedList both with a function called ItemCount(). But in List the function ItemCount() returns the number of items in the list, but in a linked list it always returns 1 because it is node based (ignore why this is so). Now, you'll make me use a function taking a List param but you send me a List = new LinkedList() and when I use ItemCount() I get 1, not what I expect (the number of elements).
